# Using smartphone to unlock HC-05 Bluetooth

Tags: android, app-inventor

I'm now doing a project, and I'm stuck on a part where I need to customize my HC-05 Bluetooth module to be password protected, and I can unlock it when I pair with the module through smartphone. I do not have any idea on that, plus I'm using MIT App Inventor to do it. So could anyone help me with it? Really appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can have the user enter a password into a text box, and only connect to the module if they enter the correct password.